# Change order in react-apexcharts

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I am using react-apexcharts to display data on chart. Chart display data from ascending order like from January to December but I need to display in descending order like from December to January.

Is there any option to change the order.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the data is depending on how you construct the x axis categories (Jan ... Dec or Dec ... Jan) and array of data before passing it up to the series options. Since you are using react version, i assume that you get the data from ajax calls. Let's say you have initial state like these:

```
this.state = {
  options: {
    ...
    xaxis: {
      categories: [],
    },
    noData: {
      text: "Loading...",
    },
  },
  series: [],
};
```

what you have to do is you can either configure the backend to return prepared data for both x-axis categories and series, or received as it is and sort it in the frontend and then set the state accordingly.